# How do I import a NMEA file into QGIS 2.8?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.8, nmea

I have some NMEA data recorded in a file - this is not a realtime application. How do I import that into QGIS 2.8?

Comment: Use a third party program like GPSBabel to [go to gpx](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Converting/NMEA_to_GPX) first? It appears [GDAL has a driver](http://www.gdal.org/drv_gpsbabel.html) that utilizes the GPSBabel program.

Answer (score 2):

There was a [nmea2qgis2 plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/nmea2qgis2/) developed a couple of years ago which was designed for QGIS 2.0. Can't say if it will work for QGIS 2.8 (also can't say if it worked at all!).

---

EDIT:

I downloaded and enabled the **nmea2qgis2 plugin** which seems to load successfully on QGIS 2.6.1. But can't test if it works as I don't have any NMEA data files:

[image: nmea2qgis2 plugin]